# how to create an array from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

I really do not know how to put the question, I hope some one would assist me. this is what I want to achieve anyway. I want to use the `google visualization` to create charts.

This is what I want to achieve.

```
var arrayNeeded = [['Population', 'Total Number Per Unit'],['Staff Count', 5686],['Student Count', 9890]];        
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
```

This is what I have:

```
var arr1 = [5686, 9890];
var arr2 = [Staff Count, Student Count];
```

How do I put these two arrays to give me the array called "arrayNeeded". here's what I have done. I'm a learner at javascript so it's kinda messy.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('custs'));
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.lgaid.length; i++)
{
    result[i] = "['"+obj.lgan[i]+"',"+ parseInt(obj.lgaid[i])+"]";
}
```

obj is an object with two arrays lgan and lgaid in it

The result gives me an array of strings like this ("['Student Count', 9890]") rather than an array of 2-column arrays

```
var result = "['Population', 'Total Number Per Unit']","['Staff Count', 5686]","['Student Count', 9890]";
```

Please, someone, help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at array.push(); or array.contact();?

Comment: @Isreal: i have answered below on how you needed it. Also, now you can have any number of values in you arr1 and arr2. and it will join and give you the correct result. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
var arr1 = [5686, 9890];
var arr2 = ['Staff Count', 'Student Count'];

var result = arr1.map(function(value, index) {
    return [arr1[index], arr2[index]];
});

result.unshift(['Population', 'Total Number Per Unit']);
```

Comment: perfect, this was the first one i tried and it worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

just use this

```
var required = [['Population', 'Total Number Per Unit']];
for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; ++i) {
  required.push([arr1[i],arr2[i]]);
}
```

the result array is in the required array.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array by mapping one the arrays using using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The 2nd parameter in the callback is the current index, and you can use it to get the item from the other array.

```js
var arr1 = [5686, 9890];
var arr2 = ['Staff Count', 'Student Count'];

var result = arr1.map((v, index) => [arr2[index], v]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer as you needed. Hope this helps

```js
var titleArr = ['Population', 'Total Number Per Unit']
var arr1 = [5686, 9890];
var arr2 = ['Staff Count', 'Student Count'];

var arrayNeeded = [];

arrayNeeded.push(titleArr);

arr1.map(function(item, index){
  var tempArr = [];
  tempArr.push(arr2[index], arr1[index]);
  arrayNeeded.push(tempArr);
});

console.log(arrayNeeded);
```